# Unity - How can I restart the score once the restart button is clicked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, button, scoring

I am having a "problem" in a game that is being developed. When the character dies from a collision to the enemy, or trigger gameobjects, it displays a game over screen, which contains a "Try Again" button to restart the game, but the score collected from the previous game remains once the restart button is clicked.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your help!!

GameOver C# script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CS_GameOverMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    

    public void RestartButton()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 1");
        Debug.Log("Game open");

    }

    public void MenuButton()
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
        Debug.Log("Main Menu open");
    }

    public void ExitButton()
    {
        Application.Quit();
        Debug.Log("Game closed");

    }

    //public void QuitButton()
    //{
    //  Application.Quit();
    //Debug.Log("Game closed");
}
```

Comment: How are you saving your score? Are you using playerprefs?

Comment: Yeah, I use player prefab to collect the food to get the score afterwards. I have also a a collect script to allow the player to collect the food to get a score calling another script called Score. Actually, the problem now is the restart button once the game over screen is displayed. When I click on try again the previous score remains.  I am not sure if I have to write any code in the game over script, or elsewhere. @TEEBQNE

Comment: Is your score static? How are you writing to the score variable? Are you saving the score somewhere using playerprefs or json/binary. It is staying persistent due to how you set it up. If you let me know this info I can help

Comment: To be more specific,  can you share the code where the score gets increased after the player collects food?

Comment: Yes. the score is static int. I am not sure what you mean with saving the score. I dont have any player prefab in the score gameobject.just the scoreText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a static field, this data will persist while the game is still running even after a reset. Inside of your `Reset` function put code similar to this.

If you would rather not grab the object by name, use this snippet.

```
public void RestartButton()
{
    ScoringSystem.theScore = 0;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 1");
    Debug.Log("Game open");
}
```

You just need to set the score back to 0 when reloading the scene as the value you have is marked as static.

Comment: I get this error due to the static. I dont know how to solve this problem. https://imgur.com/BhR1aor

Answer (score 0):

You could access the Player Object (or whichever Object holds the score) and simply set the variable to 0 (it has to be public for that).

It would work something like that:
`scoreGameObject.getComponent<"ScriptName">().scoreValue = 0`

Comment: I am kind of confused. Sorry, I am still a beginner. Where should I put that line of code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get the score class/file and reset the score

```
public void RestartButton()
{
    GameObjectWithScoreFile.GetComponent<ScoreClass>().Score = 0; // Make sure the Score var is public 
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 1");
    Debug.Log("Game open");
}
```

if you get an error because the variable is not static just make it static.

example:

```
public static int Score = 0;
```

Comment: if you have more than one instance for some reason just get the instance you want to reset and reset it.