# Unity - Resetting score to zero once the restart button is clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, restart

Actually, I have an issue in the game I am developing. The restart button does not restart the score to zero once is clicked and I do not know how to solve this problem. Therefore, I am not using any PlayerPref, but I am using a static score, scoreText as the name of the score text and ScoringSystem as the script used to increase the score.

I would need your help if is possible. Thank you!

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CS_GameOverMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
   // public GameObject scoreText;

  

        public void RestartButton()
        
        {
            Score.scoreValue = 0;
            


            
            // GameObject.Find("scoreText").GetComponent<ScoringSystem>().theScore = 0;
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 1");
            Debug.Log("Game open");
        }
    




    public void MenuButton()
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
        Debug.Log("Main Menu open");
    }

    public void ExitButton()
    {
        Application.Quit();
        Debug.Log("Game closed");

    }

  
}
```

Comment: So what else is setting the `Score.scoreValue` any chance it happens after your reset? Does your reload work at all? Try to [Debug your code with breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) ..

Comment: @derHugo that line of code you are mentioning is what I thought could work inside the restart button variable, but does not work as expected. I was trying to figure out about what line should work to reset the score to zero once the restart button is clicked. Another thing, when the player wins, a victory scene loads and one of its buttons called menu still stores the previous score once play button is clicked.

Comment: Well I see that you are setting it to `0` .. the question is is some other script setting it to a different value afterwards? And how is that static value related to your other scripts? How do you update the display when the value changed?

Comment: The static int score comes from the scoring system that is called from another script called "collect" when the food is collected. Another thing, when the player wins, a victory scene loads and one of its buttons called menu still stores the previous score once play button is clicked.    quick summary: When the player gets a score and loses the match, game over screen is displayed and the scene is reloaded as expected, but does not reset the score. When the player wins th match,  victory screen is displayed, once the menu is clicked , then play button clicked, the previous score still remains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity - How can I restart the score once the restart button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288521/unity-how-can-i-restart-the-score-once-the-restart-button-is-clicked)

Comment: The score is 0 either of the character did not collect any food, or once "Play" is clicked in the game scene to make the game functional. This is very weird

Comment: @TEEBQNE Unfortunately, it did not work. I get this problem https://imgur.com/BhR1aor

Comment: With object you mean the text, right? scoreText is where is the score.

Comment: More getting at duplicate questions are frowned upon. I would have happily answered the question in the same thread. As it is static you should access the variable by the instance name, so `ScoringSystem.theScore = 0;` if you have not changed the scripts / variable names from the other question. derHugo is right though, if you are changing the score elsewhere before the load is called, it will overwrite it.

Comment: @TEEBQNE I know what you mean, but the mods closed it. :C Anyway, the line ScoringSystem.theScore = 0; Should be in the RestartButton() (Game over script)? Thanks! I did not change any line of code from the previous question because wasn't working.

Comment: @TEEBQNE Thank you very much for your help!!!, I have put "ScoringSystem.theScore = 0" and worked just fine even in the next level 2. When the character loses the match, the restart button in the game over screen resets the score back to 0 and then I have added the same line of code in the menu button when the player wins to restart the score to 0 before loading the scene again.

Comment: Glad we could help figure out your issue. I flagged this question as a duplicate linking your original question. To let others know the problem is solved, would you mind selecting either of the answers on your previous question by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer? Whichever answered the question.

Comment: @TEEBQN I think I did it before. Actually, it shows "1 black upvote" next to the comment.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify. Selecting an [answer on your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288521/unity-how-can-i-restart-the-score-once-the-restart-button-is-clicked/67289476?noredirect=1#comment118940703_67289476). It helps others know that a question has a working answer.

Comment: I notice a long conversation here. Was the question eventually answered? If so, I would reccomend to add an answer and accept it, so to help other developers in the future.

Comment: @Marco Tizzano Yeah, it was answered, thanks. The upvote is done , but I cant select the answer as solved. Solved Message: More getting at duplicate questions are frowned upon. I would have happily answered the question in the same thread. As it is static you should access the variable by the instance name, so ScoringSystem.theScore = 0; if you have not changed the scripts / variable names from the other question. derHugo is right though, if you are changing the score elsewhere before the load is called, it will overwrite it. – TEEBQNE